# How do I make leaflet map dynamically zoom to location based on dynamic panel click?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that displays interest points and an info panel that sorts the points based on a score and displays the top 5 dynamically based on the map extent. I want users to be able to click on the panel and zoom to that point of interest on the map.

the code below shows what I have so far.

```
var info = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); /
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

        var inBounds = {},
            listed5 =[],    
            bounds = map.getBounds();


            jsonlayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
                if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {

                    inBounds[marker.feature.properties.name] = marker.feature.properties.score ;


            }
            });
            var top5Sorted = Object.keys(inBounds).sort(function(a,b){return inBounds[b]-inBounds[a]});


            var listedtop5 = top5Sorted.slice(0,5);


            info.update = function (top) {

                this._div.innerHTML = '<div class="map-navigation"><h4>Title:</h4>'+ ('1. <a href="#" data-zoom="17" data-position="'+'">'+listedtop5[0] +'</a><br>' + '2. '+ listedtop5[1]+ '<br>' + '3. ' + listedtop5[2] + '<br>' + '4. '+listedtop5[3] + '<br>' + '5. '+ listedtop5[4]) + '</div>' ;
            };


            info.addTo(map);    




        map.on('move', function() {
        info.removeFrom(map)
        var inBounds = {},
            listed5 =[],    
            bounds = map.getBounds();


            jsonlayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
                if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {

                    inBounds[marker.feature.properties.name] = marker.feature.properties.score;
                    //inBounds.push(marker.feature.properties.name=marker.feature.properties.score);


            }
            });
            var top5Sorted = Object.keys(inBounds).sort(function(a,b){return inBounds[b]-inBounds[a]});


            var listedtop = top5Sorted.slice(0,5);

            info.update = function (top) {

                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Title:</h4>'+ ('1. <a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="48.06633,7.67268">'+listedtop[0] +'</a><br>' + '2. '+ listedtop[1]+ '<br>' + '3. ' + listedtop[2] + '<br>' + '4. '+listedtop[3] + '<br>' + '5. '+ listedtop[4]) ;
            };

            info.addTo(map);


        });
        document.querySelector('.map-navigation').onclick = function(abc) {
            var pos = abc.target.getAttribute('data-position');
            var zoom = abc.target.getAttribute('data-zoom');
            if (pos && zoom) {
                var locat = pos.split(',');
                var zoo = parseInt(zoom);
            map.setView(locat, zoo, {animation: true});
            return false;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`panTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panto) method, in combination with [`zoomIn`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomin). Keep in mind that `panTo` method receives a `latlng` as the coordinates argument, so most probably you will have to transform your `locat` to a LatLng object.

```
document.querySelector('.map-navigation').onclick = function(abc) {
        var pos = abc.target.getAttribute('data-position');
        var zoom = abc.target.getAttribute('data-zoom');
        if (pos && zoom) {
            var locat = pos.split(',');
            var zoo = parseInt(zoom);

        map.panTo(new LatLng(locat[0], locat[1]);
        map.zoomIn(zoo);
        return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: That makes sense but I'm trying to  figure out what would be the best method to get the latlong information of the top5 points since they are constantly changing based on the map extent.